# libedit/readline conflict with ipython 3.2.2 on OS X 10.7 Lion

Tags: python, python-3.x, readline, ipython, easy-install

I've been trying to set up ipython 3 (running 2.7 works fine) on a mac running Lion, but can't seem to get rid of the following error:

```
192:~ mlauria$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/ipython3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages\
/IPython/utils/rlineimpl.py:96: RuntimeWarning: Leopard libedit detected - \
readline will not be well behaved including some crashes on tab completion, and \
incorrect history navigation. It is highly recommended that you install readline,\
which is easy_installable with: 'easy_install readline'
  RuntimeWarning)
Python 3.2.2 (v3.2.2:137e45f15c0b, Sep  3 2011, 17:28:59)
```

easy_install readline worked correctly to fix this on ipython 2.7, but this doesn't fix 3.2.

Comment: Does `easy_install readline` work correctly and then not help, or does it have errors installing?

Comment: I should note that `pip install readline` *does not count*, because it will (by default) install readline *behind* the system readline that uses libedit.  If you think you already have readline, you might do: `easy_install-3.2 -a readline`.

Comment: easy_install readline works correctly when fixing this error for ipython 2.7, but doesn't fix it for 3.2.

Comment: easy_install only installs things for the python easy_install is run with.  So if `easy_install readline` works for 2.7, you will need to do `easy_install-3.2 readline` or some such for Python 3.2.  You would need setuptools/distribute installed for your Python 3.2 in order to have this command available, of course.  I should note that this certainly *does* work in my experience for Python.org 3.2 on OSX 10.7.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is unfortunate as more and more Python distributions on OS X are being built with the Apple-supplied `libedit` in OS X rather than the GPL-licensed GNU `readline` library which Apple does not ship.  For instance, current 64-bit/32-bit python.org installers for OS X use `libedit` while the 32-bit-only installers currently use `readline` since `libedit` was buggy on older versions of OS X.  While the 32-bit-only installer for Python 3.2 can be installed on 10.7, it is problematic on 10.7 if you need to install any C extension modules, as that Python was built with the older 10.4u SDK and ppc archs which are not supported on 10.7.  Ideally, iPython should be modified to work correctly with either `libedit` or `readline`.  If there are Python bugs inhibiting that, bugs against Python itself should be filed.  Also, perhaps the maintainers of the `readline` package on PyPI can be persuaded to build and put a 3.2 binary package out there.

Otherwise you can build it yourself using their source distribution, assuming you have installed Xcode for Lion.  If the Python 3.2 bin framework is not in your path, you'll need to do:

```
$ export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:$PATH
```

Then if you have not already installed Distribute for Python 3.2:

```
$ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
$ python3.2 distribute_setup.py
```

Then download, build, and install the `readline` package from PyPI:

```
$ easy_install-3.2 readline
```

Or you could install a version of Python 3.2 from a third-party distributor like MacPorts which does provide a `readline` port (`py32-readline`) along with an iPython port.

Comment: thanks ned, this is very helpful - i ended up just going through MacPorts, fairly painless, in case it's helpful to anyone else i also had to run:

sudo port -f activate py32-distribute;
sudo port install py32-ipython

and then make the appropriate alias (though macports gives you the option to create it at the end).

Comment: Glad it was of help.  BTW, when you ask a question on StackOverflow you should either mark the most helpful answer as accepted or edit your question until you do get an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a command called something like `easy_install-3.2`?

Looking at [readline on PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/readline), it looks like there isn't a binary built for Python 3, so you'll probably need the relevant stuff to compile it from source (unless you can find a Python 3 build elsewhere).

Comment: To get `easy_install-3.2`, you will need to install Distribute (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) for your Python 3.2 instance, i.e. download then run `python3.2 distribute_setup.py`.  But, as noted, that won't help if there is no 3rd-party `readline` package built for Python 3.2.